# Trouble with displaying RTF-Text between Delphi XE8 and Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7, rtf, delphi-xe8, richtext

I have trouble displaying RTF-Formatted text between two delphi-Versions.

The TDBRichEdit-Control and TRichEdit-Control seem to have trouble parsing the RTF-text supplied.

Sometimes it seems as if to get it to work in XE8 you simply have to connect a TDBRichEdit to the appropriate Field in the Dataset, but the same Method would mess up the Delphi 7 Version.

So we figured we handle this via Code.
Basically we replaced the TDBRichEdits with normal TRichEdits and
supply the RTF through a stream.

```
textstream:=TStringStream.Create(CDS.FieldByName('TEXT').AsString);  
try                                                                                   
  RichEditFAPLAN.Lines.Clear();                                            
  RichEditFAPLAN.Lines.LoadFromStream(textStream);                         
finally                                                                    
  textstream.Free();                                                       
end;
```

this worked fine until about 1h ago when I decided to move the code above into it's own globally available function.

```
procedure StreamRichTextTo(ARichEdit:TCustomRichEdit; ADataSet:TDataSet; AFieldName:String);
var
  ws:WideString;
  Stream:TStringStream;
begin
  ARichEdit.Lines.Clear();
  if (ADataSet=nil) or (ADataSet.FindField(AFieldName)=nil) or (ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).IsNull) then exit;

  ws:=UTF8Decode(ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).AsString);
  Stream:=TStringStream.Create(ws);
  try
    Stream.Position:=0;
    ARichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free();
  end;
end;
```

I tried different Variations of this code. With MemoryStream, Widestring, UTF8 Encoding, AnsiString and what not.

```
procedure StreamRichTextTo(ARichEdit:TCustomRichEdit; ADataSet:TDataSet; AFieldName:String);
var
  {$IFDEF VER150}
    ws:WideString;
    Stream:TStringStream;
  {$ELSE}
    s:AnsiString;
    //Stream:TMemoryStream;
    Stream:TStringStream;
  {$ENDIF}
begin
  ARichEdit.Lines.Clear();
  if (ADataSet=nil) or (ADataSet.FindField(AFieldName)=nil) or (ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).IsNull) then exit;
  {$IFDEF VER150}
    ws:=UTF8Decode(ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).AsString);
    Stream:=TStringStream.Create(ws);
  {$ELSE}
    {
    s:=ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).AsAnsiString;
    Stream:=TMemoryStream.Create();
    Stream.Clear();
    Stream.Write(PAnsiChar(s)^,length(s));
    }
    s:=ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).AsAnsiString;
    Stream:=TStringStream.Create(s,TEncoding.UTF8);
    //Stream.WriteString(s);
    Stream.Position:=0;
  {$ENDIF}
  try
    ARichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free();
  end;
end;
```

All to no avail, the XE-RTF-Text always comes out looking either like this or as a simple '':

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 arial;}{\f1\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f2\fnil arial;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\lang1031\f0\fs20 Gie\'dftemp.: \tab 1350 - 1370 \'b0C
\par \ul\f1 Form fest verklammern und belasten
\par \ulnone\f0 
\par \tab\tab\f2 
\par }
```

What's more, the original Code with the "textstream", that I commented back in, is also not working anymore.

What I'm looking for is a code-solution that can properly handle RTF-Text between different IDE-Versions.

**EDIT:**

Here is a sample Project-Code.
The thing is, everything works fine in this project.
I have no idea why the same code does no longer work in our software and I can not reproduce it.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls, Data.DB,
  Datasnap.DBClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    REGoal: TRichEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    CDS: TClientDataSet;
    RESource: TRichEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure StreamRichTextTo(ARichEdit:TRichEdit; ADataSet:TDataSet; AFieldName:String);
var
  Stream:TStringStream;
  //{$IFDEF VER150}
  ws:WideString;
  //{$ELSE}
  //{$ENDIF}
begin
  ARichEdit.Lines.Clear();
  if (ADataSet=nil) or (ADataSet.FindField(AFieldName)=nil) or (ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).IsNull) then exit;
  try
    //{$IFDEF VER150}
      ws:=UTF8Decode(ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).AsString);
      Stream:=TStringStream.Create(ws);
    //{$ELSE}
    //  Stream:=TStringStream.Create(ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).AsString);
    //{$ENDIF}
    ARichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free();
  end;
end;

(*  Copy this to RESource

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 arial;}{\f1\fnil arial;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1031\f0\fs20 Erste Form ist eine Zulegekontrolle durchzuf\fchren.
\par
\par
\par \f1
\par }

*)


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stream:TStringStream;
begin
  if CDS.FindField('TEXT')=nil then
  begin
    CDS.FieldDefs.Add('TEXT',ftWideString,4096);
    CDS.CreateDataSet();
  end;

  CDS.Edit();
  CDS.FieldByName('TEXT').AsString:=RESource.text;
  CDS.Post();

  StreamRichTextTo(REGoal,CDS,'TEXT');
end;
```

- Just Create a new Form1
- Add 2 TRichEdits, one is called RESource and the other REGoal
- Add a TClientDataSet and call it CDS
- Add A Button
- Assign the OnClick-procedure to the button

I'll try creating the project in D7 and port it to XE8 next, maybe this will reproduce the effect.

**EDIT 2:**
Creating the Project in Delphi 7 and then Opening it in XE8 produces the same result.

My guess is, that there is something happening when the Database-Value is assigned to a String-Variable (or passed directly into the stream) which would be why I'm unable to reproduce the error.

Also maybe the Database is at fault.
it's a Firebird 3.0 Database with a VarChar-Field

Comment: maybe this is an interesting read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177204/utf8decode-in-delphi-7

Comment: Could you include a small program which reproduces the problem? See [mcve]

Comment: I tried recreating the problem with a simple project but it works just fine there.
I can not reproduce this effect.It only happens in the XE8-Machine

Comment: @GuidoG unfortunately no help.

Comment: A hint: You wrote you are using the same code in D7 and XE8.  
Sometimes D7 can be confused, if you only "Compile" the project, but not fully "Build" it. *(Especially, if you are compiling the same code with 2 different IDE and may leave pre-compiled ~ files there.)*  
My recommendation is to put that blue **Build** icon next to the compile icon, and if something is acting strange, always do a full build instead of just Ctrl+F9.

Comment: @SzakiLaci It's been some time so my memory on the problem is a bit hazy.
The original Code as seen in the answer was working fine.
IIRC the problem was that additional RTF Code was inserted or appended or left out somewhere in the pipeline which resulted in invalid RTF Code alltogether.
There I also found out that RTF has a keyword that prohibits changes to its content, which will lock up the TRichEdits if it is parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This IS the working Version of the code.
Apparently there was something wrong with the RTF-Code itself due to a bug in our Editor

```
procedure StreamRichTextTo(ARichEdit:TRichEdit; ADataSet:TDataSet; AFieldName:String);
var
  {$IFDEF VER150}
    ws:WideString;
  {$ELSE}
    ws:String;
  {$ENDIF}
  Stream:TStringStream;
begin
  ARichEdit.Lines.Clear();
  if (ADataSet=nil) or (ADataSet.FindField(AFieldName)=nil) or (ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).IsNull) then exit;

  {$IFDEF VER150}
    ws:=UTF8Decode(ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).AsString);
  {$ELSE}
    ws:=ADataSet.FieldByName(AFieldName).AsString;
  {$ENDIF}
  Stream:=TStringStream.Create(ws);
  try
    ARichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free();
  end;
end;
```